# Problem in echo array after json decode in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, json

I have this `json encode` in one row of the database, and i want echo values `name_r` and `units` and `price_change` together in the foreach , how is it?

```
[{
    "name_r": "saeed",
    "units": ["salam", "11", "11", "khobe", "22", "22", "salam"],
    "price_change": ["33", "33", "33", "44", "44", "44"]
}, {
    "name_r": "salavat",
    "units": ["55", "55", "khobe", "66", "66"],
    "price_change": ["77", "77", "77", "88", "88", "88", "99", "99", "99"]
}]
```

this is my php:

```
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $data = json_decode($row->residence,true);
            foreach($data as $datum){
            echo $datum['name_r'].'<br>';
            echo $datum['units'].'<br>'; //This is line 5
            echo $datum['price_change'].'<br>'; ///This is line 6
            }
        }
```

this php code output it is this

```
saeed
Array //Output line 5
Array //Output line 6
salavat
Array //Output line 5
Array //Output line 6
```

Why output in line 5 & 6 is `Array`, how is fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could implode the units and price_change arrays to avoid to more foreach inside the main one.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $data = json_decode($row->residence,true);
            foreach($data as $datum){
            echo $datum['name_r'].'<br>';
            echo implode(',', $datum['units']).'<br>'; //This is line 5 as string, separated by ','
            echo implode(',', $datum['price_change']).'<br>'; ///This is line 6, same as line 5
            }
        }
```

Should try the two methods and see which one is less resource consuming

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $data = json_decode($row->residence,true);
        foreach($data as $datum){
            echo $datum['name_r'].'<br>';
            foreach($datum['units'] as $d){
                echo "\t".$d.'<br>'; 
            }
            foreach($datum['price_change'] as $d){
                echo "\t\t".$d.'<br>'; 
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDITED:**
The elements that we want to recover are arrays, so it is necessary to go in a loop to print...

Comment: You should also explain why it's happening.

Comment: @Alfonso Rubalcava - Thanks, did there is not way except foreach?

Comment: Jenifer: There are several ways to do... [While](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php), [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/es/class.arrayiterator.php)... `foreach` is simple ;)

Comment: If you do not need to interact with the data, @CoBaLt2760 option works too.